# Create SQL query with WHERE .. IN condition using list of integer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection

I am not an expert of SQL and what I am trying to achieve is the following.

I have a list of integers called `PersonIds`. First of all I need to transform this list of integers to a list of strings. Why? Because as far as I have understood for the `WHERE .. IN` condition in SQL this is the kind of variable I need to feed to the query.

Then I need to modify the list of strings in order to prevent SQL injection and therefore inserting `@` before every `Id` of the list.

At last I create the query and feed the list I just created.

What I tried to do is:

```
var listIds = string.Join(",@", PersonIds, 0, PersonIds.Count()));
var query = $"DELETE FROM PersonTable WHERE PersonId IN (@{listIds})";
```

There is something I am doing wrong. To recap I need to steps:

1. preparing a list (including mechanism to avoid SQL injection) that I need to feed to the query
2. create the query using as argument the list I created

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the likely value of `PersonIds.Count`? Is it ever likely to be > 2000?

Comment: @mjwills no it's likely to be max 10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way is to add some [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/):

```
List<int> listIds = ...
connection.Execute("DELETE FROM PersonTable WHERE PersonId IN @listIds",
        new { listIds });
```

Dapper does all the hard work of figuring out how to parameterize that, while still staying *almost* close to regular TSQL. You can also optionally enable `string_split` usage if you're using recent versions of SQL Server, to minimize the parameter count and query-plan cache size.

Note that the missing parentheses is deliberate and intentional - dapper treats this slightly differently to the regular `IN (@foo, @bar)` syntax.